# How do I find the coordinates of a visible portion of a zoomed view in iOS for cropping

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, coordinates, crop

I have a UIScrollView called ScrollView containing a UIView called imageContainer that zooms correctly. I have another subview called croppingView that is a little smaller than the visible screen.

[image: StoryboardClip]

I want to capture the coordinates of the visible portion. I thought that imageContainer.frame.origin would be relative to its SuperView, which I believe is ScrollView - they are nested in the storyboard. However, logging the origin of imageContainer as I zoom shows it changing size but the origin remains constant. I expected it to become negative as I zoom in. croppingView's origin changes correctly.

When I attempt to grab the visible portion using the coordinates of croppingView, I get the wrong part of the picture. It seems that my grab is using the correct coordinates relative to the real zoomed origin, but because imageContainer.origin is wrong I get a part of the picture below what I am selecting.

This is an example of the log output:

[image: log output]

This is the code in willLayoutSubViews:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
[super layoutSubviews];
CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
CGRect croppingFrame = croppingView.frame;
croppingFrame.size.width = boundsSize.width - 40;
croppingFrame.size.height = boundsSize.height - 40;
UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (currentOrientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
//Convert the bottom left corner in the visible window to the equivalent in the zoomed scrollView and set it as the origin of the cropping frame
    croppingFrame.origin = [self convertPoint:CGPointMake(20.0, 20.0) fromCoordinateSpace:(self.window.screen.fixedCoordinateSpace)];
else if (currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    croppingFrame.origin = [self convertPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.height - 20.0, 20.0) fromCoordinateSpace:(self.window.screen.fixedCoordinateSpace)];
}
else if (currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    croppingFrame.origin = [self convertPoint:CGPointMake(20.0, self.bounds.size.width - 20.0) fromCoordinateSpace:(self.window.screen.fixedCoordinateSpace)];
}
croppingView.frame = croppingFrame;
cropButton.center = CGPointMake(croppingView.frame.origin.x+20, croppingView.frame.origin.y+20);
NSLog(@"imageContainer.frame.size: h, w = %f,%f",imageContainer.frame.size.height, imageContainer.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"imageContainer.frame.origin: x,y = %f,%f", imageContainer.frame.origin.x,imageContainer.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"imageContainer.bounds.size: h, w = %f,%f",imageContainer.bounds.size.height, imageContainer.bounds.size.width);
NSLog(@"imageContainer.bounds.origin: x,y = %f,%f", imageContainer.bounds.origin.x,imageContainer.bounds.origin.y);
NSLog(@"Cropping frame size is h,w: %f , %f =",croppingView.frame.size.height, croppingView.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"Cropping frame origin: x,y = %f,%f", croppingView.frame.origin.x,croppingView.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"Cropping frame bounds size: h, w = %f,%f",croppingView.bounds.size.height, croppingView.bounds.size.width);
NSLog(@"Cropping frame bounds origin: x,y = %f,%f", croppingView.bounds.origin.x,croppingView.bounds.origin.y);
```

}

It is obvious that I don't really understand the relationships between the various coordinate systems and what happens when I rotate the device. What is the origin of a subview and how does it change when I rotate from portrait to landscape?

What I really want is to be able to crop the visible area of the screen!

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: I think the answer may lie here:http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions